# Elasticsearch issue with alias and filter

Tags: elasticsearch

I have on Index fullData where I store documents from various sources, having one field as docSource. After that, created an alias over this fullData to have a view over source='phone' with the following code:

```
POST /_aliases?pretty
{
 "actions": [
   {
     "add": {
       "index": "fullData",
       "alias": "sourceData-phone",
       "filter": {
         "term": {
           "docSource": "phone"
         }
       }
     }
   }
 ]
}
```

I then created some Lens Visualizations, added to a dashboard and it all seemed fine.
The problem is when I want to add a filter using the "add filter" and select "docSource is", the dropdown is showing all the other sources from the main index. If I select "Web", it returns 0 rows but I don't want the user to know which sources we have available. Is there a workaround for this?

I'm using Elastic version 7.17

Thank you

Comment: I tried to reproduce in version 8.8.2, I could not. I'll try to check 7.17

Answer (score 0):

- You can try to create a new `data view` (`index pattern`) in kibana with your alias name, **sourceData-phone**.
- If you are using elastic-cloud managed ES or if you have at least platinum license you can try [document level access permission](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/document-level-security.html).